# What are the acceptable datetime format(s) for AWS QuickSight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have data with various datetime formats. Are there any specific datetime format(s) that are acceptable by AWS QuickSight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of acceptable formats is located in the Amazon QuickSight User Guide. Here is a link to the relevant section: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-date-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be worth mentioning that it is easy to add a calculated field to get a date from an epoch: [epochDate function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/epochDate-function.html)